# Deserializing array with derived objects

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have an XML document that looks something like this:
Both sound and music are derived types from audio base class. They are stored in List sounds collection. How can I deserialize that? Because doing simple (List)x.Deserialize would produce an list of base types.

```
<sounds>
 <sound name="SFX_PunchObject">
  <file name="SFX_PunchObject.ogg" size="5414"/>
 </sound>
 <music name="HWAS_Cutscene1">
  <file name="HWAS_Cutscene1.m4a" size="135049"/>
 </music>
</sounds>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you producing/serializing the data or is it from a 3rd party?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [custom serializer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SerializationOne.aspx) to deseralize from pretty much any format that contains the necessary information to populate your object..

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can use

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(ChildType))]
```

on your base class, and can then deserialize multiple types in one list into the base type.  I believe that requires having a

```
type="music"
```

attribute, instead of having different root elements, though.

You might have to implement ISerializable to get what you need.

Comment: it seems that for XmlInclude to work elements must contain xsi:type attribute

Comment: Yes, I believe that's what I said.